# Why 'dynamic' ExpandoObject throws RuntimeBinderException even if it contains the definition for a property?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Using the following sample code: (VS 2013, update 3)

```
dynamic demo = new ExpandoObject();
demo.Test = 10;
var j = demo.Test; // throws exception
```

When debugging this code and *'Break when an exception is: 'Thrown''* is checked in VS then trying to access the *existing* property 'Test' throws a `RuntimeBinderException`:

> System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'Test'

*Note: Stepping over to the next line the variable j is set correctly to 10.*

[image]

---

[image]

---

Q1: Why the exception is thrown, when the Test property definitely exists and holds the value 10 which is proved by the fact variable j successfully set this value? The exactly same exception occurs when I try to use a really non existing property name like Test2, with the difference that then the code really jumps out the block with a non handled exception...

Throwing a totally false and misleading exception, then handle internally it just does not make sense, besides it renders VS 'Break when an exception is: 'Thrown' option feature practically unusable for code what uses dynamic objects.

Q2: Yes I know this issue can be hidden by *unchecking* 'Break when an exception is: 'Thrown' option.
However this is not an option supposing a developer uses dynamic objects, and try to find exceptions in her/his code what are totally unrelated with the dynamic objects, this issue make the 'Break when an exception is: 'Thrown' option unusable, because then the debugger will stop thousands of *correct* property access statement. Is there any workaround?

Missed I something?

Thanks in advance.

---

*** Edit ***
This edit is after the correct answer.

Damir asked in his answer "Why do I have the Enable Just My Code disabled in your VS options?" Well here is the answer... I was bugged with this for a few days, and experienced that despite I explicitly check the Just My Code option, it somehow does not persist between the VS close/start sessions. Finally I found out why...

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't happen. See the source of ExpandoObject: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Actions/ExpandoObject.cs.

Comment: Ricardo, would you like a video as a proof, or believe I am not PhotoShop edited the picture :-)

Comment: Show a stacktrace please.

Comment: No need, I believe you! :-) I was just pointing you to the source, where you can try to find the reason.

Comment: There are dozens of exceptions that are thrown, caught, and correctly handled in the .NET Framework. Why do you not simply disable the "Break when thrown" option for that specific exception, and leave it enabled for all others?

Comment: Questions about a .NET framework implementation details/decisions is gonna be hard for most people here to answer.

Comment: Reproduced. But I needed to uncheck `Enable Just My Code` (in Options, Debugging, General) to see the exception, cf. the "answer" from Damir Arh.

Comment: It is somewhat interesting that _setting_ the ("new") property does not involve an exception, `demo.Test = 10`, but _getting_ it (reading the now "existing" property) throws and handles. Setting the same property again (overwriting) also happens with no intermediate exception.

Comment: @leppie The stack trace has only one "frame", it looks like this: `"   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderController.SubmitError(CError pError)"`

Comment: hvd: 1) Because after checking this option always browsing in the exception tree and uncheck this specific is a real productivity killer. 2) The point is: This exception is _false_. I was asking missed I something or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why do you have the *Enable Just My Code* disabled in your VS options?

[image]

Now you will get an additional option in Exceptions dialog to break only on exceptions which you didn't handle in your code:

[image]

If you configure VS like this, the debugger won't break any more when these internally handled exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Also, the very first time this pop-up _RuntimeBinderException occurred_ is shown, he can remove the check mark from _Break when this exception type is thrown_. Then he will see no more `RuntimeBinderException` instances. He can still see other exceptions (even handled ones) in both his own code and the BCL code, if he prefers.

Comment: Thanks Damir. This is definitely a workaround, and I missed it. Not a practical question (I mean one can say: who cares?) but still: Why on the earth someone throw and catch herself/himself an exception "System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'Test'" when it is definitely contain...?

Comment: @g.pickardou Probably because there are multiple ways in which `dynamic` can find a member. Perhaps (just a guess) it's first trying to find a `Test` property using reflection which fails and throws, catching that exception, and only then continuing searching to see if the property is made available in some different way.

Comment: @hvd   Under normal usage scenario throwing thousands of Exceptions is a bad idea. No way to explain and reason it. In this particular case in your explanation: With reflection we can always can get what properties exist, or get if a particular property exists before trying to access a not existing property. :

Comment: @g.pickardou I don't know what exactly is being cached, but I do know there's caching going on, so it wouldn't be thousands of exceptions anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using the comment made by "Jeppe Stig Nielsen".  Just uncheck the Break when this exception type is thrown, and the debugger will no longer prevent the code from running.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue recently and It was because I am trying to add an object to a list which is a property of the ExpandoObject without initializing the list first.

```
var someObjectInstance = new someObject();
var sampleExpando = new ExpandoObject();
sampleExpando.someObjects.Add(someObjectInstance);
```

The above gave me RuntimeBinding Error which was resolved by the following:

```
var someObjectInstance = new someObject();
var sampleExpando = new ExpandoObject();
sampleExpando.someObjects = new List<someObject>();
sampleExpando.someObjects.Add(someObjectInstance);
```